# style element by tag name (attribute)

Tags: attributes, styles, element

With css, How to style an element with its attribute (tag name).
for example, i have an element

```
<div xpar="karp">
blabla
</div>
```

how to aim that div with its tagname "xpar"?

Comment: `div[xpar="karp"] {color: orange;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called Attribute selectors ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)) and they work like this:

```
/* All divs with a "xpar" attribute that equals "karp" are bold */
div[xpar=karp] {font-weight:bold;}
```

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/) is a more in-depth article about them by Chris Coyier

Answer (score 1):

You would use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to style the element:

```
div[xpar=karp] {
    // some style
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Style element with xpar attribute with value of "karp":

```
div[xpar="karp"] { ... }
```

Style element with xpar attribute:

```
div[xpar] { ... }
```

This article will give you a lot more on attribute selector, including *=, $=, etc:
http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/